# Delete folders with exclusions (case)

Tags: scripting, vbscript

i found a VB script that uses FileSystemObject to delete every folder on a drive except ones i specify, **my problem is that the FileSystemObject cannot see or enumerate folder with trailing / leading - period / space, but DIR command can**,

I trying to run a command to delete all folders on a drive (it's from winPE during OS Deployment so it's ok) EXCEPT for the one i specify, this is part of what i work with which works fine but doesn't pick special named folders... is there a way i can use DIR command to feed the "Select Case"?

```
For each oFolder in oFSO.GetFolder(oEnvironment.Item("DestinationLogicalDrive") & "\").Subfolders

Select Case lcase(oFolder.Name)

Case "minint", "recycler", "system volume information", "deploy", "drivers", "_smstasksequence", "smstslog", "sysprep", "userstate"
oLogging.CreateEntry "Skipping " & oFolder.Path, LogTypeInfo
Case Else
oLogging.CreateEntry "Deleting " & oFolder.Path, LogTypeInfo

sCmd = "cmd /c rd ""\\?\" & oFolder.Path & """ /S /Q"

iRc = RunAndLog(sCmd, false)
TestAndLog iRc,"Execution: " & sCmd
If iRC <> 0 Then
If oFSO.FolderExists(oFolder.Path) Then

oLogging.CreateEntry "Failed to delete " & oFolder.Path & " will try to rename", LogTypeError
sCmd = "cmd /c rename """ & oFolder.Path & """ """ & oFolder.Name & ".bad"""
iRc = RunAndLog(sCmd, false)
TestAndLog iRc,"Execution: " & sCmd

If iRC <> 0 Then
If oFSO.FolderExists(oFolder.Path) Then
oLogging.CreateEntry "Failed to delete or rename " & oFolder.Path & " the image WILL fail with NTLDR", LogTypeError
' TODO: notify, sit and wait
End If
End If
End If
End If

End Select
```

Answer (score 1):

okay, instead of using the filesystemobject i decided to use simple DIR command in FOR loop,

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /s /a:D /b \\?\C:\*.*^|"%~dp0"\findstr /I /V /G:"%~dp0\exclusion.txt"') do Call :Delete "%%i"

:Delete

echo found %1

rd /s /q %1
```

here's what happens:

DIR list all directories on \?\C:\ recursively and outputs a bare list pipe the output to findstr which exclude names found on that text file and then calls the delete command,
the file exclusion.txt contains the items i want to exclude
thanks to you and "TheOutcaste" from this thread:
forums.techguy.org/.../833910-solved-help-r-loop.html